# How do I make my mesh have a matte black finish in cycles?

Tags: materials

How do I turn a mesh into a black mesh with a matte finish? I tried all the texture types. 
I am in cycles render.

Comment: Textures are not what you want, you want to use the Material nodes. Try a Diffuse shader

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Matte simply means diffuse.  So for a pure matte, black shader I would simply use a *diffuse shader* with the color set to *almost* black (HSV about [0,0,0.98]).  If it is pure black, it will not reflect any light and thus not look good.

*Photorealism note:  Almost nothing in the real world is purely diffuse.  To make your material look much better and more believable you might want to mix in (with a factor of about 0.05) of a* glossy shader *with a roughness of around 0.12.*

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Glad I could help!  If this solved your issue, you could click the green *accept this answer* checkmark.