# Make a blender material dull

Tags: materials

My roughness is 1 and yet I can't seem it get my material dull.

Sorry if this is a noob question, I'm very sure it is yet I've been trying for hours to figure it out.

I'd tried messing with the material in multiple ways yet I can't seem to stop my material from reflecting. I don't want the pink box not to reflect, I want the material to be dull.

As you can see in the image the roof is reflecting some of the pink color for some reason.

[image: Box reflecting on roof]

Here is my material (roughness is 0 but it doesn't make a difference whether 1 or 0):

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you post an example of what you would consider a material to be dull ?

Comment: @Gorgious Charcoal or slate would be dull materials

Comment: "The roof is reflecting color *for some reason*" In real life, the light that bounces on a colored surface will be that color. A white house in with green grass in front will be a bit greenish.

Comment: Related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24884/how-do-i-make-my-mesh-have-a-matte-black-finish-in-cycles   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_reflection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats actually not a reflection but indirect light.

you can use a light path node ([more info on the node here](https://artisticrender.com/how-the-light-path-node-works-in-blender/)) to control the color of your cube before and after light hits it.

Here is a basic node setup for your cube material:

[image]

the upper color of the mix color node controls the color of the light after it bounces off of the cube. the other color is the color of your cube itself.

Before
[image]

After
[image]

Comment: But now if I place a transparent material in front of the box, the box becomes white when looked at through the transparent material, how can I solve this?

Comment: @NidalBarada Keep in mind that "physics-bending" solutions like this usually bring more problems along the way :).

Comment: Change the light path output to diffuse ray and switch the colors in the mix rgb node. that solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this - the first Mix Shader clips out the shadow (and the color), and the second Mix Shader adds the colorless shadow back. It even works with transparency (the reason the cube looks "split" is because I placed a crude glass plane in front to demonstrate):

[image: NoCol]

EDIT: I noticed my first example caused the color to display slightly incorrectly on the cube (due to my arbitrary mix factor on the second Mix Shader). To correct this, simply use an inverted Shadow Ray as a mix factor.:

[image: NoCol2]